# What is the number of possible combinations of d nonnegative integer numbers from 0 to N such that the sum equals N (and order matters)?

Tags: combinatorics, vectors, combinations

Suppose that we are given two values: `d` and `N`.
We want to know what is the number of possible `d`-dimensional vectors of non-negative integer numbers, that vector sum is always equal to `N`.

For example, if we say `d=2` and `sum=10` the number of possible vectors is equal to `11`:

```
array([[ 0, 10],
       [ 1,  9],
       [ 2,  8],
       [ 3,  7],
       [ 4,  6],
       [ 5,  5],
       [ 6,  4],
       [ 7,  3],
       [ 8,  2],
       [ 9,  1],
       [10,  0]])
```

Or, for `d=3` and `sum=10` the number of possible vectors is `66`:

```
array([[ 0,  0, 10],
       [ 0,  1,  9],
       [ 0,  2,  8],
       [ 0,  3,  7],
       [ 0,  4,  6],
       [ 0,  5,  5],
       [ 0,  6,  4],
       [ 0,  7,  3],
       [ 0,  8,  2],
       [ 0,  9,  1],
       [ 0, 10,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  9],
       [ 1,  1,  8],
       [ 1,  2,  7],
       .
       . 
       .
       [ 6,  2,  2],
       [ 6,  3,  1],
       [ 6,  4,  0],
       [ 7,  0,  3],
       [ 7,  1,  2],
       [ 7,  2,  1],
       [ 7,  3,  0],
       [ 8,  0,  2],
       [ 8,  1,  1],
       [ 8,  2,  0],
       [ 9,  0,  1],
       [ 9,  1,  0],
       [10,  0,  0]])
```

Just in case you are interested in, here I put the code that gives you all possibe vectors:

```
import numpy as np
def combinations_recursive_inner(n, buf, gaps, tsum, accum, tot):
    if gaps == 0:
        accum.append(list(buf))
    else:
        for x in range(0, tot+1):
            if tsum + x + (gaps - 1) * tot < tot:
                continue
            if tsum + x > tot:
                break
            combinations_recursive_inner(n, buf + [x], gaps - 1, tsum + x, accum, tot)

def combinations_recursive(d, tsum):
    accum = []
    combinations_recursive_inner(d, [], d, 0, accum, tsum)
    return np.array(accum)

print(combinations_recursive(d=3,tsum=10))
```

So, is there any formula that, given `d` and `N`, tell us the possible combinations?

Comment: This is just [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: As an aside, you forgot to include that the integers be *non-negative* in the premise.  Otherwise you have infinitely many.  In case you are too lazy to read the wiki link, the end result is that it will be $\binom{d+N-1}{d-1}$.  Your second example with $d=3,N=10$ for instance yields $\binom{12}{2}=66$.

Comment: Many thanks for the point. I didn't know the name of this problem. (Please be kind to a new contributor and don't give me more down-vote :) )

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Your code seems extremely verbose.  In *Mathematica*:  `Length@IntegerPartitions[10]`.